# replace some columns with mean value with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("A","A","B","B"), y1 = c(1,2,3,4), y2=c(10,20,30,40), y3=c(1,4,10,40), y4 = c(1,0,0,0))
```

I'm looking for a way to replace all numeric columns but `y2` to the mean of that column. Desired output:

```
x   y1   y2  y3     y4
A   2.5  10  13.75  0.25
A   2.5  20  13.75  0.25
B   2.5  30  13.75  0.25
B   2.5  40  13.75  0.25
```

What's the best way to achieve that with `dplyr`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df |> mutate(across(where(is.numeric) & !(y2), mean))
```

This preserves `x` and the ordering and is pretty legible to me.

```
  x  y1 y2    y3   y4
1 A 2.5 10 13.75 0.25
2 A 2.5 20 13.75 0.25
3 B 2.5 30 13.75 0.25
4 B 2.5 40 13.75 0.25
```

Answer (score 2):

One way, using a regex to match "y followed by anything except 2". You may need to modify if your real data is not like the example.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(matches("y[^2]"), ~mean(.x)))
```

Result:

```
  x  y1 y2    y3   y4
1 A 2.5 10 13.75 0.25
2 A 2.5 20 13.75 0.25
3 B 2.5 30 13.75 0.25
4 B 2.5 40 13.75 0.25
```

Comment: I like this answer, but *technically* all numeric columns but y2 is a slightly different thing to y followed by anything except 2

Comment: you probably want `c(where(is.numeric), -matches("y2"))`

Comment: As I say, it rather depends if the real data is anything like the example. But yes, as the question mentions "all numeric columns" that's probably a good modification.

Answer (score 2):

What about

```r
library(dplyr)
df |>
  select(where(is.numeric)) |>
  mutate(
    across(
      .cols = c(-y2),
      .fns  = ~ mean(.x)
    )
  )
#>    y1 y2    y3   y4
#> 1 2.5 10 13.75 0.25
#> 2 2.5 20 13.75 0.25
#> 3 2.5 30 13.75 0.25
#> 4 2.5 40 13.75 0.25
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want to *replace* or do you want to add new columns with the means?

Also I'm not sure if your question is more about actually computing or about using
tidy_select to do the same thing to more than one variable.

If you really want to replace and don't mind writing it all out, the simple code is

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("A","A","B","B"), y1 = c(1,2,3,4), 
                 y2=c(10,20,30,40), y3=c(1,4,10,40), y4 = c(1,0,0,0))
df |> dplyr::mutate(y1 = mean(y1), y3 = mean(y3), y4 = mean(y4)) -> df
```

If you want to make it ignore just the two columns this will work.

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("A","A","B","B"), y1 = c(1,2,3,4), 
                 y2=c(10,20,30,40), y3=c(1,4,10,40), y4 = c(1,0,0,0))
df %>% 
    mutate(across(!matches("y2") & !matches("x"), ~mean(.x)))
```